# How to color a word in Vim Plugin Output

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I'm writing a Vim plugin. The main logic is written in Python (Python 3.6) with the required Vim Script wrapper code.

The plugin outputs text to user using Python print functions. For example:

```
print( "The action " + action + " has failed." )
```

How would I go about getting the word "failed" to show up in red?

Everything I've tried searching for so far comes back with syntax highlighting in Vim and ANSI color escape code rendering in Vim. Both color text in the main Vim buffer for whatever file you're looking it.

I want to color a word from the Python output from my plugin. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is that text printed?

Comment: The very bottom of the terminal., Where you would otherwise type commands or see what mode you're in.

Answer (score 2):

#### Failed attempts

My experiments confirm that *ANSI escape codes* do not work from within the embedded Python interpreter. This isn't surprising, as Vim captures the output and uses its own routines for output. As you cannot use ANSI codes with `:echo`, it's consistent that this doesn't work with `:py print`, neither. Also, in GVIM, there's no terminal attached, and the embedded terminal emulator is rather dumb.

```
:py print("The ^[[01maction^[[0m has failed.")
```

What does work (except for GVIM) is invoking an external command, because its output is directly sent to the terminal. This doesn't help you, though (unless you're willing to switch to invoking an external Python interpreter).

```
:!echo "The ^[[41maction^[[0m has failed."
```

The way to influence output coloring is via Vim's *highlight groups*, namely the `:echohl` command. Unfortunately, this **cannot** be combined with `:py print`:

```
:py vim.command('echohl ErrorMsg'); print("foobar")
```

#### Solution

You have to switch to Vim's `:echo[msg]` to make the chosen highlight group apply to the output; now, everything cleanly goes through the same API. You can either concatenate and execute a single command sequence:

```
:py vim.command('echohl ErrorMsg | echo "foobar" | echohl None')
```

Or submit multiple `vim.command()` separately:

```
:execute "py vim.command('echohl ErrorMsg')" | py vim.command('echo "foobar"')
```

Comment: This is a lot that I don't understand. :) Which is great, gives me a good starting point. I'll circle back to let you know if this is what I do.